# Who is this young person beside Trump at his victory speech?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, donald-trump

The Secret Service agent on Trump's left (our right) looks very young. Who is this person?

[image]

Comment: Next drama on Meta: "Are 'person-identification' questions on topic for this site?"

Comment: Perhaps, but there are already about 5,799 on this SE site by my count

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's Donald Trump's youngest son, **Barron Trump**.

[image: Barron Trump]

[Source](https://www.closerweekly.com/posts/donald-trump-son-barron-trump-144996/)